# Getting 7 Inch Touchscreen working on Stretch

Tags: display

I have a raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ running Stretch OS dated 3-13-2018 and am having trouble getting the touchscreen portion of my new display a GeeekPi 7 inch TFT 1024X600 display working. I have the resolution set but cannot get the cursor to be controlled via the touchscreen. I have the micro USB attached from the Pi and have rebooted several times but still no work. This is my first attempt at using a Touchscreen Display. The Display is amazing but since I am trying to use this for a Auto Entertainment Center i need the touchscreen as I dont want to have to use a mouse and keyboard. The exact display I am speaking of is: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B075QCXLPF/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o08_s02?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B075QCXLPF)      In the description it says (Extend Two USB HOST Ports；Resolution up to 1024 x 600; USB Capacitive touch control ;Free-driver, Plug and Play; ) So it came with no software and the wiki site only reflects directions on adjusting the resolution which I have working.

Does anyone know is there software that needs to be loaded in order for the touchscreen to work? Anyone with any idea on what I can try i am more then willing to try. 
Thank you
Brian Zimmer
bfpa40@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with a faulty USB Cable, what clued me off was I plugged a USB Mouse into the 2-USB Ports on the Display and it wouldnt work while it would work when plugged directly into the Pi. So I swapped out the USb Cable feeding the Display and IT WORKED. Sometimes best to think in Simple terms.. KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.